# Use Apache as a front-end server to serve images, and as a proxy between back-end server

Tags: apache, playframework, proxy

My application is built using PlayFramework. It runs on port 9000 and Apache stands as a proxy between that - it forwards requests from port 80 to my Play app.

Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName 127.0.0.1:9000
  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

My application can handle file uploads to a server. Now, I need to be able to show these files to a client.

I am able to achieve that using this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName 127.0.0.1

  # configure static file serving
  DocumentRoot /srv/appname/web
  <Directory /srv/appname/web>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # rewrite incoming requests
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond /srv/appname/web%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/appname/$1 [proxy,last]
</VirtualHost>
```

Now client can request for an image like http://some.ip.address/image.png and it works.

The problem is that I need to run my Play application and be able to serve these images at the same time - a client must be able to see uploaded images in my play app.

How could I achieve this? How could I make a request for an image when user types http://www.some.ip.address/uploads/image.png and make a request to my Play app when user types http://www.some.ip.address/main?